# What's wrong with my WPF TabItem animation?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to animate the background/gradient of my TabItem. However, I am getting an error:

> Additional information: Cannot resolve all property references in the
>   property path 'Background.GradientStops[2].Color'. Verify that
>   applicable objects support the properties.

The error occurs when I mouse over the tab item.

Here's the XAML:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border Name="Border" BorderBrush="#666" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" CornerRadius="8,8,0,0" Margin="-2,0,3,-1">
                        <!-- Some irrelevant code here -->
                    </Border>

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                            <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="#EBEBEB" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[1].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="Border"/>
                                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" To="#CDCDCD" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[2].Color" Storyboard.TargetName="Border"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#fff" Offset="0.35"></GradientStop>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#e9e9e9" Offset="0.75"></GradientStop>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.35">
                                        <GradientStop.Color>
                                            <Color A="127" R="255" G="255" B="255" />
                                        </GradientStop.Color>
                                    </GradientStop>

                                    <GradientStop Offset="0.75">
                                        <GradientStop.Color>
                                            <Color A="127" R="233" G="233" B="233" />
                                        </GradientStop.Color>
                                    </GradientStop>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I think the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` is wrong. What should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't that perhaps be zero-based indices?

```
<Storyboard> 
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[0].Color" .../> 
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background.GradientStops[1].Color" .../> 
</Storyboard>
```